# How to use ng_model in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have this textbox:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", id = "email",ng_model="email", ng_pattern = @"/[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/", @required = "required" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { name = "address", @class = "form-control", id = "address", @maxlength = "30", ng_model = "address", @required = "required", ng_pattern = @"/[A-Za-z]+ ?[0-9]+$/" })
```

When i use ng_model input text disappear but when i remove ng_model i can see email.How can i fix that? Is this some problem with angular in mvc or what?

EDIT:m getting values from API and i have first name,last name that they are readonly and i dont need ng_model for them and i can see them, but things like email and address where i use ng_model i dont see them

Comment: what do you mean by disappearing? are you setting initial value which is not setting?

Comment: im getting values from API and i have first name,last name that they are readonly and i dont need ng_model for them and i can see them, but things like email and address where i use ng_model i dont see them

Comment: in inspect element i can see value but in textbox i dont

Comment: Could you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24858552/2435473

Comment: reading the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D) it doesn't seem you need the `ng_pattern`, since `ng-model="email"` will validate for you. Did you try using the example pattern in the docs?

Comment: its not problem in pattern its problem in ng_model